# How can I create new flutter component for input select with same styles as the input text?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am responsible for adding new fields (gender and date of birth) to the registration form. I don't fully get the legacy code. I have to make the gender and date of birth field input selects but keep the styles as the others'. How to make it possible?

They made a component for the input field, here is the code https://codeshare.io/2WYKYl

This is the code for register form https://codeshare.io/aVYeY3

[image: current register form]
**Edit:**

The gender and date of birth field are input text, I want to make it select input/picker input. How can I make it without changing the styles?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get you by `input/picker`? Do you mean they should pop up Flutter Calendar Widget?

Comment: Yes. And for the gender it should be select Male or Female

Comment: Are you allowed to change the given `InputField` code, otherwise you can't do much.

Comment: No, I should keep the styles `InputField`. What I think about it is adding new components named `InputSelect` and `InputDate` and implement into this https://codeshare.io/aVYeY3 but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: It can be solved without changing `InputField` code, the final solution would be to simply copy it in another widget, add new property.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new in Flutter. What property should I add?

Comment: If you are new to flutter, I won't suggest you to copy and add property, it is easy to change the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198320/discussion-between-fauzi-padlaw-and-copsonroad).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood you clearly.

First update your given code like this:

```
this.hintText,
this.obscureText = false, // set it to true/false
this.keyboardType = TextInputType.text,
```

If you only have the `StatelessWidget` given, and you want to use it, here is how you can do it.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 12),
      children: <Widget>[
        InputField(hintText: "Email"),
        InputField(hintText: "Username"),
        InputField(hintText: "Date of birth"),
        InputField(hintText: "Gender"),
        // similarly you can proceed with other data
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: The gender and date of birth field are input text, I want to make it select input/picker input. How can I make it without changing the styles?